# C++ Opengl Glsl Shader Performance Issue

Tags: c++, performance, opengl, glsl

So recently I have been programming an fps game on my laptop but when I tried to run the game on my stationary computer which should perform better it runs slower??

Here is a couple of screenshots comparing a simple test scene with and without skybox. ( Stationary computer - Top, Laptop - Bottom)

[image: Without Skybox Stationary Computer]

[image: Without Skybox Laptop]

As you can see so far this is what I would excpect, but when I add the same skybox rendering code + shader code ( Stationary computer - Top, Laptop - Bottom)

[image: With Skybox Stationary Computer]

[image: With Skybox Laptop]

As you can see now the results are the complete opposite and I have no clue why infact if I look up or back with skybox on my stationary computer I get an fps of about 5.

Here is the shader code for the skybox:

```
#version 120
varying vec3 pl;
uniform mat4 gWM;
void main()
{
    pl = vec3(gl_Vertex);
    gl_Position = (gWM * gl_Vertex).xyww; // I have also tried with gl_ModelViewProjectionMatrix instead of gWM.
}
```

Fragment shader:

```
#version 120
varying vec3 pl;
uniform samplerCube cubeMap;
void main()
{
    gl_FragData[1] = textureCube(cubeMap, -pl);
}
```

The actual mesh rendered is a sphere.

And another thing is that my laptop can also handle my lighting calculations with 100+ fps left, but if I add those to my stationary then I get about 15.

If my stationary would perform worse in the beginning I wouldn't care about why but since it doesn't I really want to know where the fps is lost!

stationary computer specs:

CPU: Intel Core i5 @ 2.80GHz

RAM: 4,00GB Dual-Channel

Graphics: ATI Radeon HD 4800 Series

laptop specs:

CPU: Intel Core i7 @2.00GHz

RAM: 8,00GB Dual-Channel

Graphics: Intel HD Graphics 4000

**Rendering (Updated)**
For rendering I use a G-Buffer that is setup like this ( from a tutorial in deffered lighting ):

```
        glGenFramebuffers(1, &m_fbo);
glBindFramebuffer(GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER, m_fbo);

glGenTextures(ARRAY_ELEMENTS(m_textures), m_textures);
glGenRenderbuffers(1, &m_depthBuffer);
glGenTextures(1, &m_finalTexture);

for(unsigned int i = 0; i < ARRAY_ELEMENTS(m_textures); i++){
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, m_textures[i]);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, i == 0 ? GL_RGBA32F : GL_RGB8, WindowWidth, WindowHeight, 0, GL_RGB, GL_FLOAT, NULL);
    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
    glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0 + i, GL_TEXTURE_2D, m_textures[i], 0);
}

glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, m_depthBuffer);
glRenderbufferStorage(GL_RENDERBUFFER, GL_DEPTH24_STENCIL8_EXT, WindowWidth, WindowHeight);
glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_STENCIL_ATTACHMENT, GL_RENDERBUFFER, m_depthBuffer);

glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, m_finalTexture);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, WindowWidth, WindowHeight, 0, GL_RGB, GL_FLOAT, NULL);
glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT4, GL_TEXTURE_2D, m_finalTexture, 0);

GLenum status = glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_FRAMEBUFFER);
if(status != GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE){
    printf("[Error ] Framebuffer status: 0x%x\n", status);
    return false;
}
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
mWidth = WindowWidth;
mHeight = WindowHeight;
glBindFramebuffer(GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
return true;
```

**So My Question: What could be causing this? And is there a solution?**

Comment: I suspect it is a fillrate issue, beyond that it is pretty hard to say. Did you stop clearing the color/depth buffer when you added the skybox? A lot of old resources will tell you that this is an optimization you can employ with skyboxes, but on modern GPUs (which use buffer compression) it is anything but. Also, in what order are you rendering the skybox? To make it least fillrate intensive, you should draw it after all other opaque geometry. If you are already drawing that way, you might try drawing the skybox first just to over-emphasize any fillrate limitations to track the bottleneck.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman 
I render everything into a second frame buffer which contains position/diffuse/normal/texcoord texture2Ds and a depth+stencil texture and then after my lighting calculations i blit the final image to the original framebuffer. So I clear the final image buffers once before the "geometry pass". But I'm only using the diffuse texture for skybox, but for the terrain I use the others.
I'm rendering the skybox last actually I tried moving it first but that gave even worse fps.

Comment: Oh, wow. There are so many things wrong with that if you are concerned with performance optimization. You can nix the position G-Buffer and reconstruct position from depth, and you do not want to blit framebuffers unless you are trying to do MSAA resolve. Drawing a textured quad will be considerably quicker than `glBlitFramebuffer (...)` in most cases.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman I have updated my question with the code I use to set up the G-Buffer hope that is what you wanted!

Comment: 32-bit floating-point is overkill for everything except for the position buffer. Worse still, it is using 32-bit RGB instead of RGBA. Some GPUs cannot deal with RGB32F and require RGBA32F. The driver probably changes those textures to RGBA32F internally and leaves the `A` component unusable. Knowing this, you might be able to encode some extra data into the `A` components of each buffer and save 1 full buffer worth of data. Before you worry about the performance of a skybox, you should consider reducing the memory bandwidth required to render *anything*.

Comment: But the biggest improvement will come if you switch to using RGBA8 buffers to store diffuse/normals. I am not entirely sure why you need a texcoord buffer though, is this deferred shading or deferred lighting?

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman Now it has become better, I can now run at about 1200 fps without drawing the skybox. But With the skybox it still drops to about 170 fps but that is not the problem the problem is if I rotate the camera and look straight up or to the sides it goes down to 15 that is not what I want. And the texcoord buffer was something I had forgotten I even had there it wasn't used. Thanks so far!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so I got it working the problem was simple I had forgotten to divide by the sizeof(float) in the render code for the sphere so it rendered too much that wasn't even suppose to get rendered!, but it's fixed, so thanks to all for helping me get a better performance!

Answer (score 3):

When I was working on my deferred renderer I was just using a texture for depth and stencil developing on an Nividia 560ti and I had no problems.But On my HD 4650 I would not show anything just a black screen so I switched to [RenderBuffers](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Renderbuffer_Object) for depth and stencil, and that fixed my problems.The only down side of this is that they can't be sampled in shaders. I hope this helps.

Comment: considering his whole engine is a deferred shader, it would seem that sampling them is actually a big deal

Comment: for the position and normals and other attributes yes they need to stay textures, but for depth and stencil it is not needed unless you are doing more advanced things ie Depth of field and SSAO.

Comment: +1, This actually does make it perform better, so thanks for that!
But it doesn't help the fact that the skybox rendering eats up all the fps when you look at it from ceratin angles ( And also overall ). This wouldn't be a problem it's just the fact that without it's now 1400fps and with it's 70 and from ceratin angles it goes to 5.

Comment: You don't even need the position buffer if you are able to keep your depth attachment in the form of a texture. 32-bit floating-point depth is sufficient to reconstruct the position from depth in most situations. Unfortunately 32-bit Depth + Stencil is a nasty format: 32-Bit Depth + 8-Bit Stencil + 24-Bit Unused = 64-Bit. If you legitimately need a stencil buffer then you only save 32-bits per pixel through reconstruction and increase hardware requirements too (D32S8X24 is not universally supported).

Comment: Err, 64-bits. (-96-bit) for removing the position buffer and (+32-bit) for packed Depth+Stencil. Nevertheless, if you can get away without a stencil buffer you save another 32-bits. Memory bandwidth is the bane of deferred shading, so reducing the size of the G-Buffer is always an important goal.